# get the list of args you can send to an app from Terminal

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

How can I get all the args I can send to a particular app? Lets take for example Chrome:

```
/usr/bin/open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args -ARGS="someargs"
```

I am interested in the list of args it accepts. How can I ask it for the whole list?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of arguments for Google Chrome here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Other applications would provide the same kind of resource if they supported them.

I don't think you can programmatically get a list of the available flags because the application is compiled. For shell scripts, you can either inspect the script or use `man app-name` to view the user manual.